# How do i point emails to Office 365 and Exchange at the same time?

Tags: domain-name-system, exchange, exchange-2003, microsoft-office-365, microsoft-office

in the near future i will be moving a company that we support to office 365. They are currently on Exchange 2003. I will be saving each users emails to pst from their current mailboxes, then adding the 365 account to outlook and importing the pst file.

I want to be able to point all email from now to office 365 as well as still have them point to exchange 2003 so when i add their 365 account they will be up to date and other users can still use exchange without interruption.

I know this cannot be done with MX records as emails will only point to the highest priority record.

Is there another way i can approach this?

Thanks Craig.

Comment: Why did you decide to do a PST export/import rather than a staged migration?  Staged migration would be normal method and would eliminate your problem.

Comment: I have tried do to a cutover migration but it kept on failing so after hours of trying to figure it out decided this would be the route to take.

Comment: Why not fix the cutover migration?  What failed?  Did you open a ticket with MS for the cutover failure?  Your current plan is fraught with problems.

Comment: It failed trying to create a migration end point. I logged the call with MS but they were useless and supposed to get back to me within an hour and its been 5 days, i think this is the best option as we are on a very tight deadline, how is it fraught with problems?

Comment: Primarily that DNS is difficult with the way you propose - you can't do MX and autodiscover right.  Also manual PST work... meh.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments this is a non-ideal way of doing the migration.

I'd imagine that the specific issue you ask about can be worked around by setting the `TargetAddress` attribute on your users to forward mail to your Exchange online organisation.  (This is part of the staged migration process.)  If you leave the MX pointing to your on-premises Exchange you can automatically forward mail for the migrated users by setting the TargetAddress to `<user>@<Office365domain>.onmicrosoft.com`  Some of your users can have outlook connected to on-premises, some to online, mail for the online mailboxes will be forwarded there by on-premises Exchange due TargetAddress.